# Python how to mock a function that's returned by a higher-order function

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest

I'd like to mock the Pandas function `read_csv`, which in my code is returned dynamically by a higher-order function, but it seems the pytest `patch` doesn't really allow it.

```py
import pandas as pd

format_read_func_mapping = {"csv": pd.read_csv, "parquet": pd.read_parquet}

def my_func(s3_path, file_format):
    read_func = format_read_func_mapping[file_format]
    df = read_func(f"{s3_path}")
    return df
```

When I run my unit test, I have the following

```
from unittest.mock import patch

@patch(f"{MODULE_PATH}.pd.read_csv")
def test_my_func(self, mock_read_csv):
    mock_read_csv.side_effect = [my_test_data_frame]
    my_func(dummy_s3_path, "csv")
```

I expect the test would use the mock and return my test data, but it doesn't, it actually  called `pandas.read_csv` to try to read from `dummy_s3_path`.

However, if I don't dynamically return `pd.read_csv` from a mapping, just directly use `pd.read_csv(f"{s3_path}")` in `my_func`, the mock works well.

Is this a limit of pytest? Or the way I mock is incorrect?

Thanks.

Comment: Does your actual code define `format_read_func_mapping` in the module's global namespace instead of locally inside `my_func`?

Comment: Why not just use a temporary file?

Comment: @blhsing yes, I did that. Is it a problem?

Comment: @blhsing thanks for the tip. Yes, after I move the `format_read_func_mapping` into `my_func`, the mock works. I still don't understand why the solution works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're defining the `format_read_func_mapping` dict at the module level, so when the module is imported the dict is created with the value of the key `'csv'` being a reference to the original `pd.read_csv`, which does not get modified when you then patch `pd.read_csv` afterwards.

To patch `format_read_func_mapping` in the global namespace of the module, you can use [`patch.dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch.dict) to patch the specific key of the dict instead:

```
import module

@patch.dict(module.format_read_func_mapping, {"csv": Mock(side_effect=[my_test_data_frame])})
def test_my_func():
    my_func(dummy_s3_path, "csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @blhsing's comment. My actual code defined `format_read_func_mapping` in the module's global namespace, and that interfered with the `patch`.

After I move `format_read_func_mapping` into `my_func` as a local variable, the mock/patch works.